# problems with nvidia settings

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 on my Lenovo Z510. I've installed the NVidia drivers 352.63. Now when I open my NVidia X-server settings, and I click on advanced settings, nothing happens and no more options appear. There is also no option to enable Vsync, and I have desktop tearing ever since I've installed the drivers. How should I proceed?